# extract binded angularjs data from html elements with angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive contains an javascript object. I try to find with jquery all html elements which are binding to this javascript object. How can I get the binded data of the angularjs object with jquery?

Maybe the above code explains better my plan.

```
angular.module('app').directive('highlight', [
    '$rootScope', '$compile', function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'highlight.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                //this data object do we need to highlight
                scope.Tohighlight;

                $($.find('input, select')).each(function () {
                    //todo extract data if input or selection are binding data
                    //<input type="x" data-ng-model="data" /></span>
                    var data = angular.extractDataFromhtmlelement($(this));
                    //if html element contains our data add some css stuff
                    if(data ==  scope.Tohighlight)
                    {

                    }
                });
            };
    }
]);
```

I don't know if there exists an angularjs method for my purpose. How can I get the binded angularjs data model of an jquery object? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26578630/947687. Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it using `scope()` method and [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/h5Ls3dbv/)

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    var inputElement = element.find('input');
    var inputModelGetter = $parse(inputElement.attr('ng-model'));
    var inputModelSetter = inputModelGetter.assign;
    function getInputModel() {
        return inputModelGetter(inputElement.scope());
    }
    function setInputModel(value) {
        inputModelSetter(inputElement.scope(), value);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But with element.find().scope() I do get the viewmodel of the element not the binding object/property.

Comment: @Briefkasten, I have updated my answer with $parse service. Think, it is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your example. That's exactly what I need. My current problem is that the $parse(boundExpression); expression throws an "TypeError: object is not a function". When I debug the $parse object is available. Do you got any hint? My modify example http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/h5Ls3dbv/

Comment: @Briefkasten, seems you gave wrong URL to an example.

Comment: Correct URL http://jsfiddle.net/28y2rps4/ . When the user clicks on the template the setFocus function will be executed.

Comment: @Briefkasten, I don't understand what your script should do. `setfocus` is out of scope, what is the error (`data-ng-click="setfocus(error)"`)?